# How do I reslove this gradle build error?

Tags: android, gradle

I used a command to build my app.

./gradlew :app:assemblerelease.

At task :app:dexBuilderRelease. I got an error.

```
Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Failed to process: ........./app/build/intermediates/transforms/sensorsAnalyticsAutoTrack/googlePlay/release/223.jar
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dexing.DexWorkAction.run(DexWorkAction.kt:59)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AdapterWorkAction.execute(AdapterWorkAction.java:57)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:67)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:97)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.lambda$execute$0(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:63)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$$Lambda$839.00000000978A4420.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
      
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Version.fakeStackEntry(Version_2.0.88.java:0)
        at java.util.IdentityHashMap.containsKey(IdentityHashMap.java:352)
        at java.util.Collections$SetFromMap.contains(Collections.java:5513)
        at com.android.tools.r8.dex.P$g.a(:2)
        at com.android.tools.r8.dex.P$g.addString(:1)
        at com.android.tools.r8.graph.f0.collectIndexedItems(:3)
        at com.android.tools.r8.graph.Z.collectIndexedItems(:2)
        at com.android.tools.r8.graph.V.collectIndexedItems(:2)
        at com.android.tools.r8.graph.T.collectIndexedItems(:4)
        at com.android.tools.r8.graph.V.collectIndexedItems(:1)
        at com.android.tools.r8.graph.V.a(:2)
        at com.android.tools.r8.graph.V$$Lambda$3484.000000009B598550.accept(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.tools.r8.graph.V.a(:8)
        at com.android.tools.r8.graph.V.a(:1)
        at com.android.tools.r8.graph.b0.b(:2)
        at com.android.tools.r8.graph.b0.collectIndexedItems(:23)
        at com.android.tools.r8.graph.V.collectIndexedItems(:1)
        at com.android.tools.r8.dex.P.a(:48)
        at com.android.tools.r8.dex.P$i.a(:42)
        at com.android.tools.r8.dex.P$e.a(:77)
        at com.android.tools.r8.dex.b.a(:15)
        at com.android.tools.r8.dex.b.b(:24)
        at com.android.tools.r8.D8.d(:92)
        at com.android.tools.r8.D8.b(:1)
        at com.android.tools.r8.D8$$Lambda$3181.00000000A24B3020.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.W.a(:30)
        at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(:11)
        at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.convert(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:116)
        ... 36 more
```

But when I use Android Studio run button, it's ok. What diffence bewteen them?

Comment: Gradle version is 6.5. Android gradle plugin version is 4.0.1.

Comment: I am from the R8/D8 team. This looks like an issue with the D8 compiler. I have opened https://issuetracker.google.com/163274237 on the bug tracker. Could you try to change the `minSdkVersion` in your `build.gradle` to match that of the emulator/device that you are testing wiht, so see if that changes `./gradlew :app:assemblerelease`? If you have a reproduction that you can share that will be helpful in addressing this. If possible follow up on the issue tracker.

Comment: @sgjesse I got ```Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed or may have crashed)
``` after change ```minSdkVersion``` from 21 to 23

Comment: I got the reason. My disk space is too small.